# Tensorflow import pretrain model dense layer weights in another model

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, tensor

I am currently having a tensorflow trained model from which i would like to extract the weights at a given dense layer and add those to a new model i would like to train. My first model has an output of 2 class but i would like to get the first tensor of weight from a dense layer and add those value to a new model before training it. Is this possible ?

Here is a picture of what i want to do

[Model 1 and Model 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KzpZ.png)

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39941323/7560920)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring specific TensorFlow variables to a specific layer (Restore by name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941323/restoring-specific-tensorflow-variables-to-a-specific-layer-restore-by-name)